# Import model Django in MondoDB shell whith Djongo

Tags: python-3.x, django, mongodb, djongo

I want import models in django in MondoDB shell.
My model class in Django

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

I use in mongo shell it

```
from app.models import User
```

Error:

```
[js] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:6
```

Comment: As far as I know you can not import Django models. After all these are Python objects, whereas mongo db is just a shell on the database.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**: you can not import Django models in a MongoDB shell.

The mongo database does not know anything about Django. The models are constructed by writing queries to the database. For ORM queries it will make Mongo queries as well.

A model class is a python class. Mongo thus does not understand these classes, but it does not even know that there is a webapplication involved, etc. It just maintains a collection of documents and runs queries on these.

You can open a [Django **`shell`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#shell) however with:

```
./manage.py shell
```

This will load the Django apps and present a Python shell where you can for example write Django ORM commands.